# Modify DEFAULT clause while creating a table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have a little piece of code that copies (parts of) a source database (in our case MSSQL) to a target database (in our case SQLite in memory) using SQLAlchemy. As part of this copying, we copy the table information from the source to the target:

```
for table in source:
    table.tometadata(metadata_target)
    # some more stuff (hack: could alter table here)
metadata_target.create_all()
```

When copying the table, the `DEFAULT` clauses get copied verbatim. E.g. a copied column in SQLite might look like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE "TableName" (
    --  ...
    "TimeStamp" DATETIME DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()) NOT NULL,
    --  ...
 )
```

This does not work because `GETUTCDATE()` is not a function in SQLite.

I am looking for a hook into the SQLAlchemy DDL compiler (I guess) where I can either modify or suppress the generation of the `DEFAULT` part depending on the value and the dialect(s) (e.g. replace `GETUTCDATE()` with `DATE('now')` or drop a default clause with `NEWID()` completely).

I have seen [this part of the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html) (we use it to handle certain types during cross compilation), but I don't know how to employ it to handle the `DEFAULT` clause. I am not even sure whether it is the right tool. I can hack around this (by altering the table after "creation" by SQLAlchemy), but I'd prefer a more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement the GETUTCDATE function for your SQLite connection.

Comment: +1 I do this in some cases already, but `GETUTCDATE` has a more or less direct equivalent in SQLite, so I don't like to use a custom function. I currently replace this "manually", but this is a hack.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, but mess it up and your database becomes unusable.  It will work, but is not recommended.  SQLite keeps the schema in a table named sqlite_master.  You cannot write to this table normally, but using `pragma writable_schema=on` you make it possible to write.  Make whatever changes you want and then turn the pragma off.  Finally to ensure that you don't cause problems since the schema has been changed underneath SQLite, close the database and reopen it.

Comment: Now that's what I call a hack! Worth a +1 ;) My current solution basically modifies the schema in between the calls to `table.tometadata(metadata_target)` and `metadata_target.create_all()`. This is the best solution I could come up with. I was hoping that SQLAlchemy would allow me to modify the DDL directly with a hook into the compiler (like it does with the `@compiles` decorator in other cases), but this seems not to be the case, so I have to live with this hack.